# Two-language site and showing variables by .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have such files:
**index.php**

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST['cat_id'];
echo "***";
echo $_REQUEST['page'];
?>
```

and **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ru/ index.php
RewriteRule ^ua/ index_ua.php
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)/ index.php?cat_id=$1
RewriteRule ^ua/(.*)/ index_ua.php?cat_id=$1
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)/([0-9]+)/ index.php?cat_id=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^ua/(.*)/([0-9]+)/ index_ua.php?cat_id=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ index.php?cat_id=$1
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9]+)/ index.php?cat_id=$1&page=$2
</IfModule>
```

http://site2.com/ru/stranica/2/
shows:

> index.php/stranica***2

http://site2.com/ru/stranica/
shows:

> index.php/stranica***

http://site2.com/ru/
shows:

> index.php***

Why $_REQUEST['cat_id'] show **index.php**, instead **stranica** ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your regex is using greedy `.*` pattern and not using anchors where it is needed.

You can use these rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ru/?$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ua/?$ index_ua.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ru/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?cat_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ua/([^/]+)/?$ index_ua.php?cat_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ru/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?cat_id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ua/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index_ua.php?cat_id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?cat_id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?cat_id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```